# Jmeter+Jruby-JSR223 sample Request+jmeter properties are not assigned for more than 4 threads

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jruby, jsr223

I have setup ant JMeter task  which gives JMeter request with already assigned 3 properties to JMeter test plan (JMX) ,

I was reading these properties in Jruby script(JSR223 sampler) like below (for upto first 4 threads it is getting all 3 property values correctly and assigning to localvariables (pvalue1mpvalue2)..

```
pvalue1=$props.get("prop1")
pvalue2=$props.get("prop2")
pvalue3=$props.get("prop3")
```

But problem is that from thread no 5, it is started throwing below exception

```
 [jmeter] Jruby Exception is     undefined method `get' for nil:NilClass
 [jmeter] Jruby backtrace is   ["<script>:157:in `(root)'"]
```

I have java_import like this in my jruby...

```
java_import 'java.util.Properties'
```

Comment: please  reply if anye one knew about above problem... In Jruby (JSR sampler doesnot display properties or vars or ctx exposed by jmeter.. pls tell me how to expose those properties...vars...to jruby jsr223 sampler from jmeter ?

Comment: I have pretty much the same problem. I've also tried System.setProperty("org.jruby.embed.localcontext.scope", "singlethread") but that didnt help.

Comment: In JMeter 5.1 and Jruby engine 1.1.6 it happens to me only sometimes when increasing threads, but can work even with 100 threads